# Can I travel to the US and search for a job with an H1-B visa?

Tags: usa, h1b-visas

I have a valid and stamped h1b visa.Currently not in usa as it was consular notification. Now my sponsored company does not have any onsite opportunity for me. So is it possible for me to travel to usa on my own and search for a job and then look for some consultancy for h1b transfer.
 Or
 I should look for a company which can do h1b transfer . Once its approved then only travel to usa. Please tell me the feasibility of these .

Comment: Questions about long term visas (such as the H1-b) belong on [expatriates.se]

Comment: Yes it is possible. However immediately you get there you will be out of status. And by doing that you would have committed fraud/misrepresentation at your entry point.

Comment: @MusoniusRufus Please don't post answers as comments.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I will continue to do so for what are viewed as off topic questions.

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly not. Your sponsoring company signed a labor certification stating that you were essential and they might lose the ability to sponsor more H1Bs if they fire you even before you arrive.

On your end, you’d lose the H1B if you arrived without the job at the company listed on your H1B. It’s not a work-anywhere visa.